# How to "sanitize" different data inputs

Tags: software-development, data-analysis

I have an application that has different inputs. Most of them are txt files or CSV/Excel Files. They contain the same type of data, though they are formatted in different ways (order of columns different, sometimes they are separated with spaces, or tabs).

How can I achieve a sort of automation that, based on the knowledge that I know the type of output data, parses the input data "normalizing" them into the same format?

What technologies do I need to look for?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), [code fragments](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), etc. If you're looking for software, please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Comment: Are you looking for an off the shelf solution, or can you code (Python, for instance)?

Comment: I can code. Sorry for being late, I had issues with my account.

Answer (score 0):

Import each of the tables into a database, clean each one as appropriate, join them with a UNION query, and export them to CSV or whatever format your application will accept.  This process can all be automated with a SQL script.  The import and export processes will need DBMS-specific functions, but those can be automated also.

Of course, you need to be able to write SQL (or hire somebody to do so) to take this approach.

Comment: Hello, this is a manual step, that requires that I do already know the format of the input. What I was looking for was knowing if there is any kind of solution (for sure data scientist should be able to know how, I believe) that I might start studying to reach this goal. ML can be helpful, but I am not sure if that's the correct solution. Thank you!